# Is it possible to create an Azure CDN with Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-cdn, azure-storage-account

Exploring Azure CDN for our existing solution, can we use it with Azure Table storage? Does Azure Storage Support it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  Azure Storage account supports CDN.

In your Azure Storage account, you can find **Azure CDN** on left side under **Security + networking**.

You can either create new or use existing CDN for your storage account.

[image]

Use this end-to-end [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn) to deploy the same and additional knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for replying and yeah I came across this but I want to know if I can expose Azure Table Storage via CDN specifically as while selecting the origin Hostname, only two options are present 
1. Blob
2. Static Website